# combining data from two tables to count contacts, trying to use union

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have two tables. One tracks Part Shipments and the other tracks System shipments. 
I am trying to count the customer contacts in each table with the result showing me the total customer contacts for both parts and systems combined. 
I am trying to use Union and I would guess from my results I am doing this all wrong. My results end up with two entries for customers. Cust A will have a total of 9 and then another entry of 1. So I am guess there is no merge of the customer contacts and it is just creating a union of both results.

The Code I am using.

```
SELECT Count(part_shipment.Customer_Station_ID) AS Contact, 
    part_shipment.Customer_Station_ID AS Customer 
FROM part_shipment 
GROUP BY part_shipment.Customer_Station_ID 
UNION 
SELECT Count(system_shipments.Customer_Station_ID) AS Contact, 
    system_shipments.Customer_Station_ID AS Customer 
FROM system_shipments 
GROUP BY system_shipments.Customer_Station_ID 
ORDER BY Contact DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. The Union just take rows from first query and rows from second query, and "display" them ones after anothers.

Answer (score 0):

UNION requires the creation of derived tables (tables created from a query).

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM table
) UNION (
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM otherTable
)
```

I also don't think you can use GROUP BY inside the selects that make up the UNION (it's been a while since I used it so I don't remember for sure)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried to use a `GROUP BY` and `SUM` from the results of `UNION` query?